# How can I stop the columns resizing on scroll in a WPF DataGrid with row virtualization turned on?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF `DataGrid`, bound to a `DataTable` which may contain a variable number of columns. This `DataTable` can change its schema and data at runtime, whenever the user chooses a new data file to load into the app (in the example below, this is simulated by clicking the **Load Data** button).

I've set the column width to `Auto` so that columns automatically resize to fit their header text or the longest piece of row content in the column (whichever is larger). Here's the **MainWindow.xaml** from my example:

```
<Window x:Class="analog.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:analog"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="600">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="loadData" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0" Content="Load Data" Click="loadData_Click" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserAddRows="False" ColumnWidth="Auto" SelectionUnit="Cell" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And here's **MainWindow.xaml.cs**:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void loadData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var data = new DataTable();
        data.Columns.Add("A", typeof(string));
        data.Columns.Add("B", typeof(string));
        data.Columns.Add("C", typeof(string));

        Enumerable.Range(1, 50).ToList().ForEach(i => {
            var row = data.NewRow();
            row["A"] = "aaa";
            row["B"] = "bbb";
            row["C"] = "ccc";
            data.Rows.Add(row);
        });

        var longRow = data.NewRow();
        longRow["A"] = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
        longRow["B"] = "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb";
        longRow["C"] = "cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc";
        data.Rows.Add(longRow);

        dataGrid.ItemsSource = data.DefaultView;
    }
}
```

This works perfectly, except that because the `DataGrid` rows are virtual (i.e. rendered on demand when the list is scrolled, as opposed to upfront), the columns can only automatically resize to the content which is currently being displayed.

However, when you then scroll down to the bottom of the list, the column widths suddenly and dramatically change as the longer cell content scrolls into view, making for a really horrible, disorientating user experience.

Turning off row virtualisation isn't an option (e.g. `EnableRowVirtualization="False"`), as I'm loading in some large data sets and performance is unusably bad without it.

I understand the limitation on sizing when using virtualisation and I'm quite happy with that behaviour. It's perfectly OK if the columns just stay at the widths they are set to when the grid is initially rendered, but I just can't find a way to do it!

I've tried some fairly horrible hacks, including this one where I loop over the columns after the initial render and programmatically set the widths in pixels to whatever size they are currently rendered at:

```
foreach (DataGridColumn column in dataGrid.Columns)
{
    column.Width = new DataGridLength(column.ActualWidth, DataGridLengthUnitType.Pixel);
}
```

I'm currently calling this manually, by putting it in a button click handler and clicking the button after the initial data has rendered—but this has no effect whatsoever, and the resize still happens when I get down to the longer values.

So, how can I stop the columns resizing when I scroll the `DataGrid`?

Answer (score 1):

Another option (not exactly as a solution for the question, but similar situations, especially when EnableColumnVirtualization is true), is to simply set the MaxWidth property of columns. An example:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent(); 

    DataTable tab = new DataTable();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        tab.Columns.Add("A" + i.ToString());
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        DataRow r = tab.NewRow();
        for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
            r[j] = "something " + (i * i * j * j).ToString();
        tab.Rows.Add(r);
    }

    DataGrid dg = new DataGrid() { EnableColumnVirtualization = true, EnableRowVirtualization = true };
    this.Content = dg;
    dg.ItemsSource = tab.AsDataView();
    dg.AutoGeneratingColumn += Dg_AutoGeneratingColumn;
}

private void Dg_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    e.Column.MaxWidth = 100;
}
```

Comment: Setting `EnableRowVirtualization = false` worked in my case where scrolling rows into view would trigger their animation, which faded the color of the row's background color. The animation was only supposed to happen when a value changed. Virtualization caused repaints when scrolled into view.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `Width` explicitly should work. Make sure that you do this once the `DataGrid` has been loaded.

Please refer to the following sample code which works for me.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<DgItem> items = new List<DgItem>()
        {
            new DgItem() { A = "abc", B = "abc" },
            new DgItem() { A = "abc", B = "abc" },
            new DgItem() { A = "abc", B = "abc" },
            new DgItem() { A = "abc", B = "abc" },
            new DgItem() { A = "abc", B = "abc" },
            new DgItem() { A = "abc", B = "abc" },
            new DgItem() { A = "abc", B = "abc" },
            new DgItem() { A = "abc", B = "abc" },
            new DgItem() { A = "abc", B = "abc" },
            new DgItem() { A = "abc", B = "abc" },
            new DgItem() { A = "abc", B = "abc" },
            new DgItem() { A = "abc", B = "abc" },
            new DgItem() { A = "abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc", B = "abc" }
        };
        dg.ItemsSource = items;
    }

    private void dg_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridColumn column in dg.Columns)
        {
            column.Width = new DataGridLength(column.ActualWidth, DataGridLengthUnitType.Pixel);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="100"
                  Loaded="dg_Loaded">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="1" Binding="{Binding A}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="2" Binding="{Binding B}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't work in my case. This is pretty much what I'm currently doing, except that the loop over the columns is currently done in a button click handler (which I just manually click after the item is loaded) rather than the data grid load event handler.

Comment: The obvious difference between your example and my code is that you are explicitly declaring the columns and data at compile time (and setting `AutoGenerateColumns="False"`), while in my app the grid is created dynamically from the schema and data of the `DataTable` currently bound to the control (which can also change during runtime). Apologies if I should have made that clearer in the question... edited now.

Comment: I can assure you I *have* read that... but you're right, I should provide a better sample. Can I ask what software you used to capture your animated screenshot? That would be most useful!